# angular ngModel generates too many errors in browser console

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a simple CRUD page. When I do typing wrong code my browser console error count is suddenly rising. Why? Actually it has only one or two error

**19590 errors, 1 warning**

.ts:

```
  document: Document;
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.document.id); //error occurs as I expected
  }
```

.html:

```
    <select class="form-control m-input" 
       name="kategori" id="kategori" [(ngModel)]="document.id" >
      <option disabled [ngValue]="null">Please Select</option>
    </select>
```

If I remove  **[(ngModel)]="document.id"** errors has gone and there is only one error. What can I do?

Note: I haven't given new instance "document" to this issue getting occur

Comment: `When I do typing wrong code my browser console error count is suddenly rising. Why?` **Dependency**

Comment: @RameshRajendran What do you mean with dependency

Comment: Once an error occurred in the template (html) every time the change detection runs will rerender your template and cause the error again.

Comment: Did you initialize `document` object? Also, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Nour is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Try this `[(ngModel)]="document?.id"`

Comment: Your `document` variable is not instanciated. So you can't `console.log` its `id` and you can't set its value in the select.

Comment: If you can look at this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6utvhq, error occur 2 times and stop. But in my project I get this error, until  I close my page (tab), otherwise console logs same error again and again. @Nour , BunyaminCoskuner , AdreNaLiNe-DJ

Comment: It's probably you have something else to trigger change detection. In this stackblitz, there is nothing on the page when that error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you need to use the Document variable inside you component you need to inject it like below:

```
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common';

export class YourComponent {

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any){
           console.log(this.document.id);
    }
}
```

After that you can use it in your `ngModel`.

Comment: Actually  I don't want to get the same error hundreds of times.

Comment: I told you it's the change detection in your project :).

Comment: yes, I am opening page dynamically and I am using changedetector ngAfterViewInit in my project.  -> this.cdRef.detectChanges();

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize the `Document` class first like this

```
document: Document = new Document();
```

See the stackblitz Demo here: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqfjew)